# class clash with lein classloader - .class over .clj?

Tags: clojure, classloader, leiningen

If I have two jars on my leiningen classpath:

```
a.jar 
b.jar
```

And `a.jar` contains

```
c\d_init.class
```

and `b.jar` contains

```
c\d.clj
```

Then I try to load the `c.d` namespace on my project:

```
(ns e.core
  (:require [c.d :as resolutiontest]))
```

Is it guaranteed by the Clojure classloader that `c\d_init.class` will always get loaded over `c\d.clj`?

Answer (score 2):

Based on the code [here](https://github.com/clojure/clojure/blob/clojure-1.5.1/src/jvm/clojure/lang/RT.java#L421) (Clojure 1.5.1), it would seem that `d__init.class` file will get loaded over `d.clj`, as long as the modification date for `d.clj` is less that the one for the `.class` file.

```
 ...
 if((classURL != null &&
    (cljURL == null || lastModified(classURL, classfile) > lastModified(cljURL, cljfile)))
   || classURL == null) {
    try {
 ...
```